# How can I get someone's folder location (Variable)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file, location

Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\joho20\Desktop\Update 0.5.1\game.bat")
        Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

Of cource, the path of `"C:\Users\joho20\Desktop\Update 0.5.1\game.bat"` changes from PC to PC, but how can I find the `\Update 0.5.1\` folder on someone else's PC?

No matter where on the pc the folder is?

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express.

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Your question "Find it no matter where on the pc the folder is?" is a toughie, and I read it as "I want to find it anywhere on the computer". What if they have a similarly named folder, but isn't the one you're looking for? Searching for a folder through all of the folders in your computer takes a lot of time. And I wouldn't recommend starting a process from a desktop path, mostly because you don't know what the user will do with that folder or etc (what if they accidentally delete that folder?).

I would suggest always putting it in one place that it should stay at. Say "My Documents\MyProgramName\Updates\Update 0.5.1", and then follow that standard forever forward. That way you always know where to find it, and the user is aware that this has to do with your program.

However, I think the question you're really looking for is "how to I find a specialized directory path".

VB.net has these predefined and will figure it out for you. For example, if I wanted to do their "My Documents" folder I'd put

```
 My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
```

They also have "MyPictures", "Desktop", etc. saved using that method.

Comment: Ok, so System.Diagnostics.Process.Start My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments("Until Tomorrow\Update 0.5.1\game.bat") ??? I'm totally new to this... xP

Comment: If you have created that folder of My Documents\Until Tomorrow\Update 0.5.1 then yes, that would be where to put it.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments("Until Tomorrow\Update 0.5.1\Until Tomorrow.exe")) **It says: InvalidCastException was unhandeled** and points at the last ")"

Comment: The error says you are trying to convert a .exe or the string you retrieved your file from isn't a proper string. You need to take this step by step and debug it piece by piece, possibly separating each part of it into multiple lines.

Comment: Can you help me with this? If you could write the full code in a new answer that would be great ;) Also, I don't know what strings are xP

Comment: #1, stackoverflow is not here to do your code for you. This is meant to help coders stuck in a rut #2, if you don't know what something as basic a string is then anything I tell you will probably go over your head. I know I sound mean, but it is the truth. I suggest you look into taking some basic coding tutorials like at codeacademy, and learn about variable types.